# How to create a 2008 database using SQL Server Management Studio 2012?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Is it possible and if so, how, to created a 2008 version database using SQL Server Management Studio 2012?  The database is also 2012, so I guess it needs to be converted somehow.

I need to take a copy of a database (which I have done), remove a lot of data from the copy (also done), back it up, and then transfer it to a server that has SQL Server 2008 on it, and finally restore it from the backup.

Comment: You can't restore a backup onto an older version of SQL Server.  The Import Data wizard will let you copy the data from your other database into a 2008 DB, which might be enough to do what you want.

Comment: @marc_s your comment is too good to not be an answer.

Comment: @alroc - this is such a FAQ that it should really be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @alroc: converted to an answer (and expanded a bit)

Comment: Found a solution here: http://superuser.com/questions/468578/move-database-from-sql-server-2012-to-2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this.

If you have the SQL Server 2012 engine, your databases are of version 2012 - you cannot "convert" those back.

What you can do is script out the commands needed to create the database, and run those on a SQL Server 2008 machine.

Or you could connect to a SQL Server **2008** engine / instance from your SQL Server 2012 Mgmt Studio and create the database there.

Fact is: the **engine** determines the internal version of the database files - you cannot switch that to something else by using a script or tool or anything.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create Sql Server 2008 Database using Sql Server 2012.

Instead, if you want to migrate data from Sql server 2012 to Sql server 2008, you can simply use excellent tools like [this](https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/).

I personally use this tool to migrate data between different versions of Sql Server and it always works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**,

You can create an Sql Server 2008 Database using Sql Server 2012. It's just more steps:

If you create new database:

1. Create new database.
2. Right click on database.
3. Go to **properties**.
4. In properties **options** page link
5. Click on **options**.
6. Select Compatibility level drop-down list and select the desired database **compatibility level**.

Comment: This doesn't create a 2008 database: you cannot e.g. wire up the raw data files to a 2008 server.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680%28v=sql.110%29.aspx: "Compatibility level provides only partial backward compatibility with earlier versions of SQL Server. Use compatibility level as an interim migration aid to work around version differences in the behaviors that are controlled by the relevant compatibility-level setting."